# Google play detects android advertising ID in my Unity game. Where?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

Google Play removed my Unity game from their market, because, as they say, it uses **Android advertising ID**. The problem is, the game **doesn't contain any ads**. It doesn't even have **any packages** that might use this advertising ID. (There is only Text mesh pro.) So, what can possibly be the source of the damned "android advertising ID"? It already sounds to me like a scary ghost, because it's the 3rd time when this game has been removed from google play because of this advertising ID, and I am really pissed off, because I don't know how to appease them at last, besides inserting the privacy policy notice (for which I have no real reason).

What might be a deeper problem is that the game is derived by copying from my another project that actually did contain ads. And the derivation ("save project as") didn't go smoothly. Maybe, this Android ID somehow jumped over from the original project, which contained adds, to the new one, which doesn't contain them? :)

And the last point: The Analytics service is turned on in this game. I suppose this doesn't have anything to do with the Android ad ID specifically. But I now imagine it could be another problem for google play, and they would deactivate it again if I don't turn it off. Or do they?

Comment: yeah probably analytics collects the advertsiment id, turn it off if you're not really using it. Also, providing a privacy policy is a good idea, I put a privacy policy button in all my android games and now there is no problem with google

Comment: OK. BTW, do you use the same privacy policy url address for all your games?

Comment: yes, I use the same